# Preventing my player from clipping into an object that has a trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ladder object and to climb it I use a trigger which is attached to the ladder object and a climbing script attached to my player. Climbing up the ladder is fine and my player never clips into it, however when descending the ladder from the top, that's when the issue occurs.

In my photo I have the trigger pretty far out in front of the ladder to reduce the amount of clipping but it is not enough. I can't move the trigger further out because then the gap between the ladder and trigger will be too great which will result in my player just falling straight down and missing the trigger. So if I have a ladder up against a wall, my player will clip through both the ladder and into the wall as I am climbing down.

[image]

What I have been trying to do is somehow descend the ladder without clipping into it but since I am using a trigger, I'm not sure if that is possible. My code is a very simple OnTriggerEnter using the col tag and a bool for movement, but my only attempts to solve this have been to adjust the box collider of the ladder itself.

Comment: do you need to know its still within the trigger? Im guessing not - one thing you could do is only have trigger areas top and bottom not the whole length of the ladder?

Comment: I attempted this just now. My player still enters the trigger while clipping into the object, and then if the distance between the two triggers is too great, my player will just bounce off the ladder. My only other idea was to maybe add an invisible platform at the top of the ladder that my player can stand on and then drag the trigger out even further to prevent clipping, but I think that would look extremely poor if my player was floating mid air.

Comment: hmm, the platform idea isnt bad you know, the ladder should have a collider and say "around" it should be some triggers, so top to get on/off same at the bottom.. but that while on platform you can only go up/down... and if the platform is the right size and position you can position it so that the player isnt clipping the ladder

Comment: I am going to try this and see how I go. I was also thinking, is there a way to somehow "push"  my player away from the ladder once I enter the trigger? So for example when I am standing on top of the ladder and enter the trigger, for a split second before I am able to start climbing down, my player will move slightly away from the ladder

Comment: you can have a collider collider :P not a trigger..